# Azure Log Stream not Logging

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

Very simply issue, not certain how to fix it. I've deployed a MVC .NET application to Azure, and added the following controller.

[image]

Here is what my Azure diagnostic log setup looks like:

[image]

And for good measure, the relevant sections of my web.config:

[image]

My problem is that the logs aren't being written to either the *Log stream* or the *LogFiles* folder in the FTP drive given by Azure. I have two other very similar applications logging without problem - however this one refuses to log. Is there setting somewhere that would implicitly stop logging?

**Note** - I'm certain the log statements are being executed, as I can reach the home/index page without problem once published.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Level to Verbose? Does that change anything? Also, have you looked at the Live Log Stream to see if they show up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you're missing here is an actual listener being configured. Try to add following code to your `web.config`:

```
<system.diagnostics>
     <trace>
       <listeners>
         <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
             type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener,
             System.Web,
             Version=4.0.0.0,
             Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </listeners>
     </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

and

`<trace enabled="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" mostRecent="true" pageOutput="false" />`

If I remember correctly, the default trace listener is not logging data in a manner consumable by Azure. Personally I'm using Application Insights for getting all the data, still it required me to pass a listener explicitly.

Comment: This was the correct solution. I wasn't able to find WedPageTraceListener on Nuget, and I ended up going with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution using aspnet core 3.1, take a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1